# How can I find $x$ such that $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{bx+c}$, given $a,b,c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, problem-solving, computational-mathematics

Everything I've read about modular arithmetic generally concerns doing things in some "mod m" world where "m" is some constant.  But I'm perplexed how to tackle modular arithmetic problems where the aim is to find the modulus which produces some result.

More specifically: **"Given positive integers $a,b,c$, how can I go about efficiently finding $x$ such that $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{bx+c}$?"**

For example, with $a=2021$, $b=89$, $c=1932$, I'm looking for $x$ such that $2021x \equiv 1 \pmod{89x+1932}$.  By brute force search, I happen to know that this is solved by $x=83$, but surely there's a better way...

For what it's worth, in the problems I'm concerned with $c=a-b$ (as hinted by the example numbers given above), but I'm not sure how useful that is if there's a more general technique anyway.

Comment: Are $a,b,c,x \in \Bbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Yes, positive integers, will edit.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $ $ [Completing the product (rectangle)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651073/242) yields $$\begin{align} ax - 1 &= (bx+c)y\\[.2em] 
\iff (bx+c)(a-by) &= ac+b\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Now find factors $\,d\,$ of $\,ac+b\,$ of form $\,bx+c,\,$ i.e. $\,d\equiv c\pmod{\!b}$.

OP has $\, ac+b = 419\cdot 9319 = $ product of primes, so only a few factors to test.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Since $a,b,c,x \in \Bbb{N}$
$$ax \equiv 1 \mod bx+c\Rightarrow ax=(bx+c)y+1\Rightarrow x=\frac{cy+1}{a-by}\in \Bbb{N} \Rightarrow a-by \gt 0 \\ \Rightarrow 0 \le y \le \lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor$$
so you're searching for $y$ in a  bounded set...With no further information about $a,b,c$ you have to make the computer search for $y$ in this set, as *brute force* would be the only possibility..

Comment: Such a brute force search will be very slow if $\,a/b\,$ is large. Then it will generally be much quicker to exploit the innate arithmetical structure and employ factorization - see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque And if *big* prime factors are not involved?? Moreover if there are *big* numbers involved, it's not quite easy to be sure they're primes..first you have to check every number smaller than $\sqrt{n}$...

Comment: Generally solving a diophantine equation of this form is equivalent to factoring integers, as in my answer. So generally one cannot do any better than to employ a fast integer factorization algorithm (which generally will be *much* faster than a brute-force search).

Comment: Maybe, but your method needs a composition of multiple algorithms (prime finder, diophantine equation solver ...)

Comment: Not maybe, but *definitely*. Brute-force (trial division) integer factorizations algorithms become impractical many orders of magnitude sooner than do the best known factorization algorithms.