# how can I find Integer solutions for the two variables equation?

Tags: diophantine-equations

how can I find Integer solutions for the following equation:

$$900 X \, Y + 210 Y + 30 X - 3 \times 10^{100} + 7 = 0$$

Comment: I tried to know if I can find x and y are both integers for two variables equations without search factors.

Comment: This is equivalent to $(30X+7)(30Y+1)=3\times 10^{100}$. That should quickly yield the answer.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas, but how I can find the integer solutions?

Comment: There aren't any. The left side is never divisible by $3$.

Comment: How you know that "The left side is never divisible by 3"?

Comment: if (30X+7)(30Y+1) = 50437, then what are the  integer solutions?

Comment: [Same method](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/898577/242) as I described in you prior question.

Comment: the left side of the equation is odd and therefore cannot be 0

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $(30 X + 7)(30 Y +1) = \ldots$

Comment: if (30X+7)(30Y+1) = 50437, then what are the integer solutions?  any way to solve without searching factors?

Comment: What do you mean by "without searching factors"?  A solution provides a factorization of $50437$ where one factor is congruent to $7 \mod 30$ and the other to $1 \mod 30$.