# $p$ is a prime iff there exist a unique $m, n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I got this question in one of the whatsapp group I am in:

> $p$ is a prime iff there exist a unique $m, n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
>   $$\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}$$

Does this question even make sense.

I can pick $m=2, n=3$ then I get $p=6$ but it is not prime. Is this result true?

Comment: It says iff there exist **unique** $m,n$...

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260931/242) for the general method to solve such diophantine equations (same problem but with sum vs. difference). It uses:  **completing a square generalizes to completing a product**.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233046/number-of-solutions-for-frac1x-frac1y-frac1n-where-1-leq/767623#767623

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $p$ is prime. Then by assumtion we have $$(n+p)(p-m)=p^2$$ and we obtain the following cases: 
$$n+p=p^2$$ and
$$p-m=1,$$ which gives
$$(m,n)=(p-1,p^2-p)$$ or
$$n+p=p$$ and $$p-m=p,$$ which is impossible or
$$n+p=1$$ and $$p-m=p^2,$$ which is impossible again.

Id est, we got an unique solution.

Also, by the same way, we see that if $p$ is not prime so we get more systems and we don't get an unique naturals $m$ and $n$.

Comment: For those  wondering where the transformed equation comes from: it is a special case of the general method [described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260931/242), i.e. **completing a square generalizes to completing a product**.

Comment: Nice solution. Is there any tie in with the result being $m=\phi(p)$ and $n=\phi(p^2)$?

Comment: @ Keith, I think we got it accidentally, but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 8):

$$\dfrac12 - \dfrac1{3}=\dfrac16$$
$$\dfrac13 - \dfrac1{6}=\dfrac16$$
$$\dfrac14 - \dfrac1{12}=\dfrac16$$
$$\dfrac15 - \dfrac1{30}=\dfrac16$$

so there is no unique representation and $6$ is not prime

*Added*

When $p$ is prime the unique representation is $$\dfrac1{p-1} - \dfrac1{p(p-1)}=\dfrac1p$$

If $p=ab$ with both $a>1$ and $b>1$, then you will at least also have  $$\dfrac1{a(b-1)} - \dfrac1{ab(b-1)}=\dfrac1{ab}=\dfrac1p$$

Comment: I think we need to p[rove that if the representation is unique then $p$ is a prime.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg - that may have been the WhatsApp question, but I read this question as why this does not apply to $6$, the answer being that it does not have a unique representation

Comment: (+1) It might be nice to say why $\frac1{p-1}-\frac1{p(p-1)}=\frac1p$ is unique.