# $a\in \mathbb{N}$, $p$ prime, $a<p$ prove that $a\mid p+1\iff\exists\, b,c\in\Bbb N:\dfrac{a}{p}=\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$a\in \mathbb{N}$, $p$ prime, $a<p$ prove that $a\mid p+1\iff \exists\, b,c\in\Bbb N:\dfrac{a}{p}=\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}$

my attempt:

$a\cdot b \cdot c=p\cdot(b+c)$ .

i dont know how to use the given
$a\mid p+1$

Comment: In one direction, have you tried looking at an example?  For example, try to find $b$ and $c$ such that $\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} = \frac{3}{17}$.

Comment: Same as the linked dupe (rewrite it as $\,1/p = 1/(ab) + 1/(ac)\,$ then apply the dupe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $ a \mid p+1$ so there is $\lambda$ such that $\lambda a =p+1$. Now divide by $ \lambda p$ & we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{a}{p} = \frac{1}{\lambda} + \frac{1}{p \lambda}.
\end{eqnarray*}

The other implication: We have $ \dfrac{a}{p}=\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}$ or $abc=p(b+c)$.Multiply this by $a$ & rearrange to $(ab-p)(ac-p)=p^2$.

This gives three possiblities $ab-p=1$ or $ac-p=1$ & the result follows.
Or $ab-p=p,ac-p=p$ which gives $ab=ac=2p$ so $a=1$ or $a=2$ and again the result follows.

Comment: You only proved one direction. The problem requires both.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yeah right ... I missed that.

Comment: The "multiply and rearrange" is an example of [completing a product](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260931/242), a generalization of completing a square. This is a standard technique for this type of diophantine equation.  Please try to avoid posting more dupe answers to FAQs.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit what do u mean multiply this by $a$ ? what is your $a$ to multiply can u make more clear the steps please ?

Comment: $abc=p(b+c)$ ... multiply this by $a$ ... $a^2bc=ap(b+c)$ ... rearrange & add $p^2$ to both sides ... $(ab)(ac)-p(ab+bc)+p^2=p^2$ ... note that this will factorise to give the next equation.