# Integer solutions to $ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{2018} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We need to find integer solutions to

$ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{2018} $

and this is equivalent to the problem $ \frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{n}{2018n} $

so i must solve the sistem $ a+b=n $ and $ ab=2018n$ for some integers 'n'

so i must find only integers value roots of the polynomial

$ a(n-a)=2018n $

and i can not go further

Comment: Well, $2018 = 2\times 1009$ and $1009$ is prime... so if you know that $a(n-a)=2018$ what can you say about $a$?

Comment: Your equation should be $a(n-a)=2018\,n$.

Comment: Using both of the above comments, both $(2)$ and $(1009)$ must be present in the collective prime factorizations of $(a)$ and $(n-a)$.

Comment: +1 : to your question.  I know that this is self-indulgence, but it is actually a pleasure to read a posting where the original poster shows work.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1779351p11715323. Does this help? You can use [Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/) to search your queries before posting to avoid duplicates.

Comment: $a=b=4036$ will work

Comment: A general method for equations like this is to [complete the product (rectangle)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260931/242) - see the linked dupe.