# How can I solve the folowing Diophantine equation with two unknowns?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, prime-factorization, linear-diophantine-equations

> Find one integer solution to the following Diophantine equation:
>   \begin{equation*}
> \\\forall \,x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\\
> 6xy + x - y = 274
> \end{equation*}

The resultat ist $x = 9$, $y = 5$ (Obtained with [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6xy+%2B+y+-+x+%3D+274) )

I need to know a method that allows me to reach such a result. How can I calculate the value of these two variables in a Diophantine equation?
For example: 6xy + x - y = 458

Comment: But, the equation is not linear.

Comment: you can use this site. It does a step-by-step solution or just a solution but it also provides the method Bill Dubuque mentioned in his answer. so you basically have everything in one neat package.

https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ This type of diophantine equation is solvable by a generalization of completing the square. Namely, completing a *square* [generalizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651073/242) to completing a *product*, using the AC-method, viz.

$$\begin{eqnarray} &&axy + bx + cy\, =\, d,\ \ a\ne 0\\
\overset{\times\,a}\iff\, &&\!\! (ax+c)(ay+b)\, =\, ad+bc\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

So the problem reduces to checking which factors of $\,ad+bc\,$ have above form, a finite process.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{274+y}{6y+1}=x$

As $x$is an integer, if integer $d$ divides both $274+y,6y+1;d$  must divide $6(274+y)-(6y+1)=1643$

For integer $x,6y+1$ must divide $1643=31\cdot53$ whose divisors are $\pm1\pm31,\pm53$

Comment: In case anyone wonders, solving it this way ends up being essentially equivalent to the method in my answer using the AC method to complete the product.

Answer (score 1):

This is @Bill Dubuque's answer in more detail.

I don't know what you mean by $\mathbb Z_0$.

$$ \forall x,y \in \mathbb Z_0, \quad 6xy + x - y = 274 $$

\begin{align}
   6xy + x - y        &= 274 \\
   36xy + 6x - 6y     &= 1644 \\
   36xy + 6x - 6y - 1 &= 1643 \\
   6x(6y+1) -1(6y+1)  &= 1643 \\
   (6x-1)(6y+1)       &= 1643
\end{align}

\begin{array}{|cc|cc|}
\hline
   6x-1 & 6y+1 & x &y \\
\hline
   1    & 1643   & \ast & \ast\\
   31   &   53   & \ast & \ast\\
   53   &   31   &    9 &    5\\  
   1643 &    1   &  274 &   0\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not quite understand the table
How do you get on the numbers 31 and 53?

Comment: @DaríoA.Gutiérrez  Listed is the four ways of multiplying two integers to get the product 1643. I got it by going to Wolfram Alpha and typing in Divisors[1643].

Comment: Know you what an algorithm used Wolfram Alpha by Divisors[1643] to extract the integer solutions (9, 5)?

Comment: @DaríoA.Gutiérrez - You solve 6x-1=53 and 6y+1=31.