# How to solve $xy=5x+5y$ for integer solutions

Tags: diophantine-equations

I did a bit of research and as I understand it would probably involve Diophantine equations. Unfortunately I have no idea where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(x-5)(y-5)=xy-5x-5y+25=25$

Now we have proved $(x-5)(y-5)=25$. Because both $x$ and $y$ are integers, both $x-5$ and $y-5$ are integers. Factorizing 25 gives the following possibilities:

> $25=1 \times 25$
>
> $25=5 \times 5$
>
> $25=25 \times1$
>
> $25=(-1) \times(-25)$
>
> $25=(-25) \times(-1)$
>
> $25=(-5) \times (-5)$

All possible values of $x-5$:

> $1,5,25,-1,-25,-5$

The corresponding possible values of $y-5$:

> $25,5,1,-25,-1,-5$

Now all integer solutions appear:

> $x=6,y=30$
>
> $x=10,y=10$
>
> $x=30,y=6$
>
> $x=4,y=-20$
>
> $x=-20,y=4$
>
> $x=0,y=0$

Comment: Still no idea of what or why I should do :/ Probably should have mentioned that I have zero experience with equations like this one. I derived it from math problem in my school exam, although I found the solution by trial and error I would like to learn how to solve it in a algebraic way too. I hope that explaining it won't be too much of a hassle. Thanks.

Comment: @MadRabbit I edited my post. Now the way to solve this equation is more explicit.

Comment: @apparent Thank you! I think while researching this topic I even read a more theoretical explanation that at its core was pretty similar to yours. Yet without the practical example I just couldn't grasp the concept or understand that it could be applied here... Thanks again for the throughout explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ This type of diophantine equation is solvable by a generalization of completing the square. Namely, completing a *square* [generalizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651073/242) to completing a *product*, using the AC-method, viz.

$$\begin{eqnarray} &&axy + bx + cy\, =\, d,\ \ a\ne 0\\
\overset{\large \times\,a}\iff\ &&\!\! (ax+c)(ay+b)\, =\, ad+bc\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

Now we need only test when $\,ad+bc\,$ can be split into two factors of the above form. A nonzero integer has only finitely many splittings into two factors, so only finitely many cases need testing.

Comment: +1, Although I have already accepted an answer, yours is quite useful as well, especially the mentioning of theoretical concepts used. If you have any additional resources in the same vein as this equation, I would appreciate if you updated your answer with them. Thank you! :)

Comment: @MadRabbit If you chase the links I gave you will learn about the AC-method and its (ring-theoretic) generalizations - which can prove very useful in diverse contexts.

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you like, begin in straightforward algebraic fashion, namely by first solving for $y$ in terms of $x$:

$$xy=5x+5y\implies xy-5y=5x\implies y={5x\over x-5}={5(x-5)+25\over x-5}=5+{25\over x-5}$$

It's at this point that the number theory comes in:  In order for $y$ to be an integer, we need $x-5$ to divide $25$, which is to say $x-5\in\{\pm1,\pm5,\pm25\}$, for a total of six pairs $(x,y)$ that solve the equation.

The real key step here consists of not stopping at $y={5x\over x-5}$, but realizing that $5+{25\over x-5}$ is a more useful expression for the problem at hand.

Comment: Algebraically,  this is equivalent to the method in the earlier answers, i.e.  there is no essential difference between $\,(x-5)(y-5) = 25\,$ and $\,y-5 = 25/(x-5).\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque, the point I'm trying to make in this answer is that you can approach the problem by starting out with a standard tactic, which is to solve for one variable in terms of the other.  So yes, the methods are algebraically equivalent, but I see the approaches as different.