# Finding integer solutions to sum of reciprocals of x and y

Tags: diophantine-equations

> $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{13}$$

Given the sum of reciprocals of $(x,y)$, what's a method to find integer solutions for an equation similar to the above? I've been wondering and I haven't really found something online.

If you could point me to resources on stuff related to this, that would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: Dupe of [Integer solutions of $xy+9(x+y)=2006$ \[Completing a product / rectangle\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651030/integer-solutions-of-xy9xy-2006-completing-a-product-rectangle) (clear denoms then complete the product)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you start by manipulating the equation as follows

$$\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y} = \dfrac{1}{n}$$

$$nx+ny = xy$$

$$0 = xy-nx-ny$$

$$n^2 = xy-nx-ny+n^2$$

$$n^2 = (x-n)(y-n)$$

Then, all the solutions are of the form $(x,y) = (n+a,n+b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are complementary factors of $n^2$, i.e. $n^2 = ab$.

The idea to add $n^2$ to both sides in line 4 is known as [Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick) in case you are curious.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

$(x+y)/(xy)=1/13$, $xy=13x+13y$, $xy-13x-13y+169=169$, $(x-13)(y-13)=169$ and it's all downhill from there.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).