# $20/71 \cdot 5/4 = (20+5)/71$. How to algebraically represent this oddity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

While doing math the other day, I ran across this strange equation: $$\frac{20}{71} \cdot \frac{5}{4} = \frac{20 + 5}{71}$$

At first I tried to represent it as $$\frac ab \cdot \frac{\frac ad}{d} = \frac{a + \frac ad}{b}$$ But this turned out to not hold true for all $a$ or $d$ (though it did for all $b$), and it also turned out to not be algebraically equivalent anyway.

My partner did point out the following explanation: $$\frac{20}{71} \cdot \frac{5}{4} = \frac{20 \cdot 5}{71 \cdot 4} = \frac{5 \cdot 5}{71} = \frac{25}{71}$$ However, if possible I'd like to generalize to some relationship of the structure $$\frac ab \cdot \frac cd = \frac{a + c}{b}$$

What's going on here?

Comment: $b$ is irrelevant. You can write the target relation as $d=\dfrac{ac}{a+c}$, or $\dfrac1d=\dfrac1a+\dfrac1c$.

Comment: Regarding the relation $\dfrac1d=\dfrac1a+\dfrac1c$, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3719034/409).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the cancellation you did on the third line, it's clear to see that the equality on the fourth line will always hold so long as $$ca=d(c+a)$$ This equation always has the integer solution $a=c=2d$, so you can vary $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ to generate solutions to the expression, such as $d=6$ yielding: $$\frac{12}{b}\cdot\frac{12}{6} = \frac{12}{b}\cdot 2 = \frac{12}{b}+\frac{12}{b}=\frac{12 + 12}{b}=\frac{24}{b}$$ Moreover, we may want to ask: *if we choose any $a,c\in\mathbb{Z}$, can we always find a satisfying $d\in\mathbb{Z}$*? I can hypothesize that we can, but I'll come back to rigorously proving it later. Maybe consider giving it a try on your own. Because we're seeking integer answers (I imagine), I recommend taking a modular algebra approach to solving $ca=d(c+a)$ for $d$.

Comment: What should be the approach if we are looking for solutions over the Reals?

Comment: @Fireextinguisher_101 Then, simply specify $$d = \frac{ca}{c + a}.$$

Comment: @user2661923 Oh yes, right, didn't see it the first time.

Comment: As for your hypothesis, $a = 1$ and $c = 2$ yields $d = \frac 23$, so it's disproved unless I'm misunderstanding you.