# Finding the number of a solutions to a non linear equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have a non linear equation which is $\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} + \frac{1}{\lfloor y \rfloor} = \frac{1}{11}$.
I also have another equation which is $\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor} + \frac{1}{\lfloor y \rfloor} = \frac{1}{60}$. I have the floor function as I only need it to return integer values. I'm succeeding with that, but I'm struggling to find the number of integer solutions to these. Does anyone know how it's done?
Thanks a lot

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3719029/finding-integer-solutions-to-sum-of-reciprocals-of-x-and-y .