# Finding positive integer solutions to $\frac{4}{x}+\frac{10}{y}=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

> Find the positive integer solutions for: $\frac{4}{x} + \frac{10}{y} = 1$

I had calculated the solutions manually but it was a very tedious process. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: It's a finite problem, with the possible solutions in a limited range.  Simple search sounds like it should be nearly optimal.

Comment: Perhaps it helps a bit to rearrange to get $y = \frac {10x}{x-4}$ so $(x-4)\,|\,10x$.

Comment: Extending the comment of @lulu, if $x$ is odd, then $(x - 4)$ is odd, which implies that $(x - 4)$ divides $5x$ which implies that either $(x - 4)$ divides $5$ or $(x-4)$ divides $x$.  Similar considerations/conclusions may be present under the hypothesis that $x \equiv 2\pmod{4}$ or $x \equiv 0\pmod{4}$.  Anyway, exploring these ideas, while they **might not** help, would be my first try.

Comment: I'd write it as $(x-4)(y-10)=40$.

Comment: Clear denom's then [complete the product](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651073/242).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\leq y$

$$1=\frac{4}{x}+\frac{10}{y}\leq \frac{4}{x}+\frac{10}{x}=\frac{14}{x}$$

$$x\leq 14$$

$$y=\frac{10x}{x-4}$$

$$5\leq x\leq14$$

$x=5,y=50$

$x=6,y=30$

$x=8,y=20$

$x=9,y=18$

$x=12,y=15$

$x=14,y=14$

Let $y < x$

$$1=\frac{4}{y}+\frac{10}{y}< \frac{4}{y}+\frac{10}{y}=\frac{14}{y}$$

$$y < 14$$

$$x=\frac{4y}{y-10}$$

$$11\leq y\leq13$$

$x=24, y=12$

$x=44, y=11$

Comment: But what if $x>y$: say $x=24$ and $y=12$?

Comment: @John Bentin Thanks, I edited the solution.