# how many pairs satisfy the given equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many integers satisfy the following equation

$$\frac{6}{x}+\frac{4}{y}=1$$

I tried combining and I get

$$6y+4x=xy$$

This gets confusing so I just tried trial and error and found three points $(-6,2),(2,-2),(3,-4),(-18,3)$ But this method seems a bit tedious.

Comment: It's a finite problem.  You can't have both of them big in absolute value.  So,  if nothing else occurs to you, just do the simple search.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Note that [Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick (SFFT)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick) can be used here.

Comment: $(x-6)(y-4)= 24$

Comment: The [method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651073/242) described in the dupe applies here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By manipulating the equation, you get:
\begin{equation}
xy - 6y - 4x = 0
\end{equation}
Then, by using Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick as @John Omielan mentioned in the comments, you can turn this equation into the form $(x-a)(y-b) = ab$, which is in our case:
\begin{equation}
(x-6)(y-4) = xy - 6y - 4x + 24 = 0 + 24 = 24
\end{equation}
Then, you can list out the factors of $24$ in pairs. The table becomes:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{$x-6$} & \text{$y-4$} \\ 
\hline
\pm24 & \pm1 \\
\hline
\pm12 & \pm2 \\
\hline
\pm8 & \pm3 \\ 
\hline
\pm6 & \pm4 \\
\hline
\pm4 & \pm6 \\
\hline
\pm3 & \pm8 \\ 
\hline
\pm2 & \pm12 \\ 
\hline
\pm1 & \pm24 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Solving for $x,y$ in these factors would give you the list of solutions.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).