# How can I find natural number solutions to $\frac{186-x}{11x+1}=y$?

Tags: diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

I'm trying to find solutions to $\frac{186-x}{11x+1}=y$, where $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$. I've been researching Diophantine equations to try and solve this, but everything I've found is in the format $ax + by = c$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that $x$ must be a small integer for the fraction to be an integer. By simple enumeration, you get 0, 2 and 8  as solutions.

Comment: @PierreCarre: And $x = 186, y = 0$ clearly works as well.

Comment: @Dan I ruled out $x=186$ because I am considering that $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$.\

Comment: @Dan I guess I also shoulf have ruled out $x=0$ !

Comment: Duplicate of [Integer solutions of $xy+9(x+y)=2006$ \[Completing a product / rectangle\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651030/integer-solutions-of-xy9xy-2006-completing-a-product-rectangle)

Comment: $11xy+x+y=186$. $11xy\geq 11y$, $11xy\geq 11x$. $13(x+y)=11x+11y+2x+2y\leq 11xy+11xy+2x+2y=372$. $x+y\leq \frac{372}{13}$. $x+y\leq 28 \Rightarrow11xy\geq 158\Rightarrow xy\geq\frac{158}{11}$. $xy\geq 15$. $xy\leq \frac{184}{11} \Rightarrow xy\leq 16$. $xy=15 \Rightarrow x+y=21$. No integer solutions. $xy=16\Rightarrow x+y=10$, $(x,y)=(2,8)$ or $(x,y)=(8,2)$

Answer (score -1):

$$11xy+x + y = 186$$
$$121xy +11x + 11y = 2046 $$

Note that
$$(11x+1)(11y+1) = 121xy + 11x + 11y + 1$$

Together
$$ -1 + (11x+1)(11y+1) = 2046 $$
$$ (11x+1)(11y+1) = 2047= 23 \cdot 89 = 1 \cdot 2047$$

Answer (score -1):

For what positive integer values of $x$ is $y = \frac{186-x}{11x+1}$ a positive integer?

Clearly, $y = \frac{186 - x}{11x + 1} < \frac{186 - x}{11} < \frac{186}{11} = 16 + \frac{10}{11} $.  So $y$ must be at most 16.  What are the bounds on $x$?

$$1 \le \frac{186 - x}{11x + 1} \le 16$$

$$11x + 1 \le 186 - x \le 176x + 16$$
$$12x + 1 \le 186 \text{ and } 186 \le 177x + 16$$
$$x \le 15 + \frac{5}{12} \text{ and } x \ge \frac{170}{177}$$
$$1 \le x \le 15$$

This is a small enough solution space to brute-force.  When we do that, we find two solutions:

- $x = 2, y = 8$
- $x = 8, y = 2$