# Determine the side lengths of a right triangle if they are integers and the product of the legs’ lengths equals three times the perimeter.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Determine the side lengths of a right triangle if they are integers and the product of the legs’ lengths equals three times the perimeter.

I tried this question for 3+ hours and I get 6 and 0 every time. Stuck now and don’t know how to approach it.

I did it like this:-
Let x and y be the base and height of right triangle respectively.
Then $xy = 3(x + y + \sqrt {x^2 + y^2})$

$xy - 3x - 3y = 3\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$

$xy - 3x - 3y + 9 = 3\sqrt {x^2 + y^2} + 9$

$(x-3)(y-3) = 3(\sqrt {x^2 + y^2} + 3)$

then comparing these two products with every possible combination.

This question is from **Number Theory by Titu and Dorin** Page 160

Comment: Just look at [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2003_Indonesia_MO_Problems/Problem_8). Your equation gives $(x-6)(y-6)=18$.

Comment: Thanks! I did it in a different way, let me add that.

Comment: As per first comment, square, cancel $xy,\,$ then [complete the rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651073/242) as in the linked dupe.

Comment: All posts on this site are questions, and all questions about diophantine equations are number theory questions – so your title is doubly redundant.